# How to correct DataFrame header containing whitespaces.

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and actually started with R.

My problem is that I am unable to debug key errors from my pandas dataframes. Here is part of the code:

I read in a data frame from excel with following commands.

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(directorytofile)
os.listdir('.')
file = dataset
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
df1 = cl.parse('Sheet1')
```

Now when i want to select a header with a blank space like

> Lieferung angelegt am

(It's German sorry for that)

I get the key error. I tried different ways to delete blank spaces in my headers when building the dataframe like:

```
sep='\s*,\s*'
```

But it still occurs. Is there a way for me to see where the problems happen?
Obviously its about the blank spaces because for headers without everything works fine.

Comment: Have you tried `pd.read_excel( <exelpath>, sheet_name='Sheet1)`? if you want to select a header using `df['header name']`with a white space in the middle the separator uses an extra '\' so it would be `df['header\\sname']`

Comment: I just tried and still get a key error. With and without sep= '\s*,\s*'

Comment: ok, then try doing `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()`and then select the header without blank spaces like `df['headername']` since the strip will take out the white spaces from the column name

Comment: thank you i tried it but still have blank spaces in the headers. when i use print(df1.columns.tolist) it gives me out the headers with blank spaces even after your tipp. why wont the headers change?

Comment: Try: `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip().replace(" ","")` it will surely remove the blank spaces

Comment: when i do this i get the Attribute Error: 'Index' object has no attribute replace. i tried to let our the strip() but that leads to a situation that only my first columns name "Lieferung angelegt am" converts to "Lieferungangelegtam" but the rest stays the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178840/discussion-between-jalazbe-and-ernsthaft).